# I transferred about 0.54 BTC and I cannot find this on Blockchain.com. Can anyone help?

Tags: transactions, blockchain

I'm hoping someone more onto it can help me find or understand exactly what happened when I xferred my BTC from an exchange (Dasset) to my wallet.

I transferred about 0.54 BTC to bc1ql8wxn65d7crka2gr4f3gcgnynv23hvqg6akxef

When I searched for transactions under this address nothing appears on Blockchain.com.
I know I have transferred to this wallet before but I can't even see those transactions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also transferred this about 18 hours ago now.

Comment: What is the name of the software wallet you use? If it's custodial, it might be some scam. Have you got the confirmation from exchange that the money was sent and transaction has been made? Sometimes exchanges take some time to withdraw. Are you using HD wallet, or one address all the time? If latter, it is weird that magically some transactions just disappeared.

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for the response.
I use Dasset as an exchange and Exodus as a wallet.
I just noticed that my BTC Wallet address on Exodus has changed since I last used it (I have the option to use 2 different receive addresses, one I've used in the past and the other is new - if that makes sense).

Comment: Dasset didn't transfer any money to bc1ql8wxn65d7crka2gr4f3gcgnynv23hvqg6akxef. What did Dasset customer support say when you spoke to them about this?

Comment: So Dasset finally responded to me.
Dasset - "It wasn't process because it was bech 32 address".

Comment: I'm not sure what that means but they've apparently still have my BTC somewhere, its just not showing as available on the exchange.

I'm waiting for them to get back to me with what that is and how I can get my BTC to my wallet.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would use Blockstream.info or mempool.space, not blockchain.com for your online block explorer.

Second, depending on the exchange, they could batch withdrawals at a certain time each day, or they could set a very low fee, which means it would take a long time to be confirmed.

As was said in the comments, you could've been scammed. I have never heard of Dasset before.

Lastly, for each transaction, generate a new receive address to ensure privacy.